# Line to Line Intersection In 3d Space

Tags: 3d, line-intersection

How to find the Line to Line Intersection In 3d Space ? Can anyone give me the equations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at **Goldman, Ronald, Intersection of Two Lines in Three-Space, Graphics Gems, p. 304.**